Intermittent Section Reload/Glitch on Scroll in Next.js App
I’m encountering an issue with my Next.js app where page sections initially load correctly, but after scrolling down and then scrolling back up, they glitch. The sections seem to reload with a brief white space, then appear in bits and parts before displaying fully again, even though the DOM is already loaded. I haven’t implemented any dynamic reloading logic, and this happens in a way that disrupts smooth scrolling.
Here’s a reference to two sites experiencing similar behaviour:

https://thegrandregent.com/
https://www.15cacb.com/

Any guidance on potential causes or solutions would be appreciated!
